# Unity 3D Tools - Kit Tools not showing

Tags: unity-game-engine

Basically, I've imported the 3D Tool Kit via Unity Asset Store, but I cannot find the Kit Tools menu. I've been looking everywhere to a fix for this issue, but I can't find anything about it.

Any ideas on how to fix this? This has been going on for a couple of days.

Unity version: Unity 2019.1.0f2

What I see:

[image]

Comment: Right click on your imported package -> reimport. Or relaunch Unity. If both does not work, try manually delete the package and import again. See if any warnings were given.

Comment: Tried all of them, they didn't work